# Distributed Computation for large data-data processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I have a huge time series data and I want to do data processing using spark`s parallel processing/distributed computation.
The requirement is  looking at the data row by row to determine the groups as specified below under desired result sections, I can't really get spark to distribute this without some kind of coordination between the executors

```
t- timeseries datetime sample,
lat-latitude,
long-longitude
```

For instance : Taking a small part of sample data-set for explaining the case

```
t   lat long
0   27  28
5   27  28
10  27  28
15  29  49
20  29  49
25  27  28
30  27  28
```

## Desired Output should be :

```
Lat-long    interval
(27,28) (0,10)
(29,49) (15,20)
(27,28) (25,30)
```

I am able to get the desired result using this piece of code

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

 val df = Seq(
  (0, 27,28),
  (5, 27,28),
  (10, 27,28),
  (15, 26,49),
  (20, 26,49),
  (25, 27,28),
  (30, 27,28)
).toDF("t", "lat","long")

val dfGrouped = df
.withColumn("lat-long", struct($"lat", $"long"))

val wAll = Window.partitionBy().orderBy($"t".asc)

dfGrouped.withColumn("lag", lag("lat-long", 1, null).over(wAll))
.orderBy(asc("t")).withColumn("detector", when($"lat-long" === $"lag", 0)
    .otherwise(1)).withColumn("runningTotal", sum("detector").over(wAll))
.groupBy("runningTotal", "lat-long").agg(struct(min("t"), max("t")).as("interval"))
.drop("runningTotal").show
}
```

But what If the data gets into two executors then the data will be like

### Data in executor 1 :

```
t   lat long
0   27  28
5   27  28
10  27  28
15  29  49
20  29  49
25  27  28
```

### Data in executor 2 :

```
t   lat long
30   27  28
```

How should I get the desired output for large amount of data.There must be smarter ways to do this ,distributing this with some kind of coordination between the executors so as to get that result.

Please guide me through a right direction,I have researched about the same but not being able to land up to a solution.

PS: This just a sample example.

Comment: Are you able to create a single cluster with many machines? Then the dataset can be visible as one dataset and it will be easier to operate on it.

Comment: @wind Can you please elaborate.

Comment: As I unserstand your description you have 2 separate data clusters (HDFS or whatever) and you have a problem with join of this data. Am I correct?

Comment: No ,Its like if I have a time series data in cassandra and I need to do some processing which is to be done in parallel manner so that when it would be distributed in different partitions and then processing would be applied on different partition,but at that the end I aim to get the above mentioned result.

Comment: OK, I got it. In this case you shouldn't work on partitions directly. Spark is designed to apply operations like map, reduce, group by, etc for the entire dataset. If you want to apply operation on specific group of rows you can use e.g. reduceByKey.

Comment: Is that what you want to say: how spark calculate aggregation operations on splitted data across executors?

Comment: yes And @slmn how can we address this on time series data.

Comment: @experiment "This just a sample example" - the problem is or "data distribution"? Remember that your code is almost exclusively sequential and there is one one output partition at the moment.

Comment: sample example refers to the data I have posted @user8371915 I posted the code just to make it clear what kind of result I want ,because sometimes its not clear from the explanation what the op really wants! I aim towards using the parallel processing feature and getting the desired result  which I am not able to get via above code if run on cluster node.

Answer (score -1):

You can address this with a UDAF.
First of all, you could add one column  thats represent the t column partitioned in a number of executor you have. Something like executorIndex = t % ((max(t) - min(t)) / numExecutors).

Then you can apply your UDAF grouping by executorIndex.

Your UDAF need store a Map with a String key (for example) thats represents one lat and long pair, and a int[] thats represents the maxT and the minT for this lat-long key.

Please ask if you need more extensive explanation.

Hope this help...

PS: I'm suming that there are some time relation between same lat and long, something normal if your are tracking some movement...

Comment: Appreciate your efforts but please provide a more extensive explanation.